# rpcbind not started at boot on centos 7 with systemd

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, centos-7

I need rpcbind service to be active after boot, so I installed it with yum, then started it by:

```
systemctl start rpcbind
```

it works. However after reboot it did not start. So I checked it with:

```
systemctl is-enabled rpcbind
```

and it showed: *static* which mean that some other service need it to boot, the service is rpcbind.socket, so I checked it and the rpcbind.socked showed that it is enabled (systemctl is-enabled rpcbind.socket returned enabled) but it does not work how it should

after boot when i execute:

```
systemctl status rpcbind
```

it show: *failed (dead)*

I have been searching for a while now this but without any luck, if anybody know a solution to this or faced this problem in the past then please help.

I'm using centos 7.1

if you need more information i can get it when i get to work tomorow

Comment: What version of `rpcbind` are you using?

Comment: Does disabling selinux temporality do anything different?

Comment: You can garner some info on why it is failing by running `journalctl -xn`. If that is not enlightening (in my experience, hardly ever) you may: 1. search for error messages in /var/log: `grep -nrI rpcbind`. This will produce much output, you will have to wade thru it. 2. Start rcpbind by hand, `rpcbind -dw`, and study its output.

Comment: Although I had a same problem but got an another error message, I solved here; http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256232/152138 Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem on Debian 8 aka Jessie and, although systems are different, [this solution](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/05/msg00618.html) could help, if you don't mind to alter configuration files.

Create file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/rpcbind.conf`:

```
#Type Path        Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
d     /run/rpcbind 0755 root root - -
f     /run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr 0600 root root - -
f     /run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr 0600 root root - -
```

Create `/etc/systemd/system/rpcbind.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=RPC bind portmap service
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
Before=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -f -w
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
Alias=portmap
```

and enabled above unit:

```
# systemctl enable rpcbind.service
```

Create `/etc/systemd/system/nfs-common.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=NFS Common daemons
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-common start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nfs-common stop

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Enable it with:

```
# systemctl enable nfs-common
```

Presumably, that should do the trick for CentOS as well.

It also looks like there is a newer version of rpcbind-0.2.3, which has [native systemd support](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2015-July/133472.html), but haven't try it...

Answer (score 0):

On centos 7.4, simple fix:

Create file: `/etc/systemd/system/nfs-client.target.d/10-rpcbind.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Wants=rpcbind.service
```

disable and reenable rpcbind

```
sudo systemctl disable rpcbind
sudo systemctl enable rpcbind
```

restart